# How to remove UNNotificationContentExtension displayed view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I used `UNNotificationContentExtension` to survey from the user.

[image]

Condition is I do not open the parent app.

Here is the emoji action

```
    if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 12.0, *) {

        // API call here
        self.extensionContext?.dismissNotificationContentExtension()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Each emoji have actions. When user tap the emoji I will send the response into server and remove this notification. Everythings will happens on the extension part

**What's the issue?**

Using `dismissNotificationContentExtension` notification dismiss and hide instant. Its again found in the notification screen. How could I remove this notification when user tap emoji button.

Comment: Which notification screen are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how my solution working.
Cons: All delivered notification of the same category removed instead of doing remove current message.

```
@IBAction func btnActionHappy(_ sender: Any) {
    
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in
            if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 12.0, *) {
                self.extensionContext?.dismissNotificationContentExtension()
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }

            let matchingNotifications = notifications.filter({ $0.request.content.categoryIdentifier == "debitOverdraftNotification" })
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: matchingNotifications.map({ $0.request.identifier }))
            
            print("Somethings")

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using UNUserNotificationCenter & UNNotificationContentExtension protocol

Add action using UNUserNotificationCenter

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.delegate = self  
center.requestAuthorization (options: [.alert, .sound]) {(_, _) in 
}  
let clearAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "sadEmoji", title: "Emoji", options: [])
let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "NotifCategory", actions: [clearAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
 center.setNotificationCategories([category])
```

Add a delegate method of the protocol UNNotificationContentExtension in your extension's view controller

```
 func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) {
    if response.actionIdentifier == "sadEmoji" {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: "NotifCategory")
    }
    completion(.dismiss)
}
```

Try it and let me know it works.

Comment: Where I will put those codes of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate ?
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.delegate = self  ........ ?

Comment: Here is the sample code. Please refer https://github.com/yayitserica/UNNotificationContentExtension-Blog

Comment: Many Thanks. I will Check it.

Comment: Notification remove working now. However, The emoji will come as a actionsheet Not like UI which I  Uploaded. What do you think this issue?

Comment: For that, you need to add your own view for NotificationCenterViewController's storyboard(MainInterface.storyboard). You need to do more for this. Take help from this - https://medium.com/better-programming/building-custom-interactive-remote-push-notification-in-ios-4ffdba0b5281. Please accept my answer if it resolved your main issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your cordial support. Your help get me to figure out this.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the current notification using `removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers:)`.

```
var notification: UNNotification?

func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    self.notification = notification

    ...
}

@IBAction func btnActionHappy(_ sender: Any) {
    if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 12.0, *) {
        extensionContext?.dismissNotificationContentExtension()
    }

    if let identifier = notification?.request.identifier {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
    }
}
```